# Identify bug found eating wood table

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This bug came out of a hole in a wood table.

I'm in south-west France but since we bought that table one year ago, it was most probably in the table when we bought it so it could be from anywhere.

I'd like to know what it is.

[image: Bug]
[image: Hole]

More context and pictures in https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/232607/holes-in-wood-furniture-identifying-the-cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an entomologist at all, or even in Europe, so take my answer with a grain of salt.

I think this is a beetle of the [long-horn beetles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longhorn_beetle), which are all beetles that have a larval stage that borrow in wood. In particular I think this is in the genus *[Clytus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clytus)* and may be *[Clytus arietis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clytus_arietis)*, which is quite common in [Europe and North America](https://www.eol.org/pages/3410678). There are other species in the genus that look pretty similar too (e.g. *[C. rhamni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clytus_rhamni)*, so I can't be sure).

*C. arietis* is pretty small - about 10-18 mm, which looks about right for your hole size, and it has very similar patterns on its elytra. It is also hairy, as yours is. Apparently it is called the "wasp beetle" as it is a [Batesian mimic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batesian_mimicry), and may even make a buzzing noise when disturbed.

Comment: Thanks. The Clytus aeietis is much more yellow but the patterns totally match, so I believe it is definitely from the same family.